# mysql help trying to compare time

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

I'm prepping to add a new column ('closed_date') to my mysql database that is calculated based on a datetime field ('scrape').

Specifically, if the time of the field scrape (which is datetime) is > 6pm then set closed_date to the date of scrape with a time of 23:59:00.  Else set closed_date to scrape interval -1 days with a time of 23:59:00.

I'm stuck getting the time comparison to work.

Here's the fiddle schema...

```
drop table if exists mytable;
create table mytable (
scrape datetime,
average_rating int,
number_of_ratings int,
factored_rating int);
insert into mytable
select '2014-05-29 00:13:55',5,2,3 union all
select '2014-05-29 00:14:42',4,1,5 union all
select '2014-05-29 21:08:18',12,3,1 union all
select '2014-05-30 00:14:46',11,4,2 union all
select '2014-05-30 21:08:22',8,2,12;
```

Here's the SQL...

```
SELECT
    scrape,
    DATE_FORMAT(scrape,'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY,
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('18:00:00','%T'),'%T') SIXPM,
    @x := IF(@TIMEONLY > @SIXPM, DATE_FORMAT(scrape, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:00'), DATE_ADD(scrape, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) close_date
FROM mytable
```

The result:

```
SCRAPE                  TIMEONLY    SIXPM           CLOSE_DATE
May, 29 2014 00:13:55+0000  00:13:55    18:00:00    2014-05-28 00:13:55
May, 29 2014 00:14:42+0000  00:14:42    18:00:00    2014-05-28 00:14:42
May, 29 2014 21:08:18+0000  21:08:18    18:00:00    2014-05-28 21:08:18
May, 30 2014 00:14:46+0000  00:14:46    18:00:00    2014-05-29 00:14:46
May, 30 2014 21:08:22+0000  21:08:22    18:00:00    2014-05-29 21:08:22
```

The IF is always FALSE even when TIMEONLY is greater than SIXPM.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: FYI... I've been playing with the @ prefix.  I'm pretty sure @SIXPM <> SIXPM, but I was trying it anyway.

Comment: I figured it out.  The TIMEONLY field wasn't available for the IF comparison, so I had to make another temp field (@tim). I'll post the answer when my 8 hour delay is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The TIMEONLY field wasn't available for the IF comparison, so I had to make another temp field (@tim)...

```
SELECT
    scrape,
    @tim := DATE_FORMAT(scrape,'%H:%i:%s'),
    @six := DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('18:00:00','%T'),'%T'),
    IF(@tim > @six, DATE_FORMAT(scrape, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:00'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(scrape, INTERVAL -1 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:00')) close_date
FROM mytable
```

Now the result is what I expect:

```
SCRAPE                      CLOSE_DATE
May, 29 2014 00:13:55+0000  May, 28 2014 23:59:00
May, 29 2014 00:14:42+0000  May, 28 2014 23:59:00
May, 29 2014 21:08:18+0000  May, 29 2014 23:59:00
May, 30 2014 00:14:46+0000  May, 29 2014 23:59:00
May, 30 2014 21:08:22+0000  May, 30 2014 23:59:00
```

p.s. I ended up doing the field update via python:

```
for row in cur:
    print row
    stkid = row[0]
    # check if after 5pm close...
    if int(row[1].strftime("%H")) > 17:
        cldt = row[1].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    else:
        # else it's in the wee hours, so we need to subtract a day
        cldt = (row[1] - relativedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print "greater than five pm...", row[1].strftime("%H"), row, cldt
```